# Threads not exiting?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, producer-consumer

I am trying to write a program to solve the producer consumer problem with threads in C++, and from what I can tell the program works fine until the very end when the threads are supposed to exit with the join() function. (The Product object is a simple data container).

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <random>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <chrono>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <stack>
    #include <thread>
    #include <mutex>
    #include <atomic>
    #include <condition_variable>
    #include <Product.h>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    const int max_items = 100;
    atomic<int> itemNum(0);
    atomic<int> numProducersWorking(0);
    stack<Product> items;
    int maxBuffer;
    float storeSales[10];
    float monthSales[12];
    float totalSales;
    mutex xmutex;
    condition_variable isNotFull;
    condition_variable isNotEmpty;
    
    int intRand(const int & min, const int & max) {
        static thread_local mt19937 generator(time(0));
        uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(min,max);
        return distribution(generator);
    }
    
    float floatRand(const float & min, const float & max) {
        static thread_local mt19937 generator(time(0));
        uniform_real_distribution<float> distribution(min,max);
        return distribution(generator);
    }
    
    void produce(int pId)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(xmutex);
        int day, month, year, id, regNum;
        float saleAmnt;
        Product item;
    
        id = pId;
        day = intRand(1, 30);
        month = intRand(1, 12);
        year = 20;
        regNum = intRand(1, 6);
        saleAmnt = floatRand(0.50, 999.99);
    
        item = Product(day, month, year, id, regNum, saleAmnt);
    
        isNotFull.wait(lock, [] { return items.size() != maxBuffer; });
        if(itemNum < max_items)
        {
            items.push(item);
            itemNum++;
        }
    
        isNotEmpty.notify_all();
    }
    
    void consume(int cId)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(xmutex);
        Product item;
    
        isNotEmpty.wait(lock, [] { return items.size() > 0; });
        item = items.top();
        items.pop();
        storeSales[item.getStoreID()-1] += item.getSaleAmnt();
        monthSales[item.getMonth()-1] += item.getSaleAmnt();
        totalSales += item.getSaleAmnt();
    
        isNotFull.notify_all();
    }
    
    void producer(int id)
    {
        ++numProducersWorking;
        while(itemNum < max_items)
        {
            produce(id);
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(intRand(5, 40)));
        }
        --numProducersWorking;
    }
    
    void consumer(int id)
    {
    
        while(numProducersWorking != 0 || items.size() > 0 )
            {
                consume(id);
            }
    
    }
    
    
    int main()
    {
        int p, c, b;
    
        p = 5;
        c = 5;
        b = 5;
    
        maxBuffer = b;
    
        vector<thread> prodsCons;
    
        auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
        //create producers
        for(int i = 1; i <= p; i++)
        {
            prodsCons.push_back(thread(producer, i));
        }
    
         //create consumers
        for(int i = 0; i < c; i++)
        {
            prodsCons.push_back(thread(consumer, i));
        }
    
        int x = 0;
        //wait for consumers and producers to finish
        for(auto& th : prodsCons)
        {
            th.join();
            cout<<"thread "<<x<<" joined"<<endl;
            x++;
        }
    
        auto stop = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
    
        cout<<"Store-wide total sales: "<<endl;
        for(int x = 1; x <= p; x++)
        {
            cout<<"  store "<<x<<" sales: $"<<storeSales[x-1]<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"Month-wise total sales: "<<endl;
        for(int x = 1; x <= 12; x++)
        {
            cout<<"  month "<<x<<" sales: $"<<monthSales[x-1]<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"Total sales: $"<<totalSales<<endl;
        cout<<"Simulation time: "<<duration.count()<<" microseconds"<<endl;
    }
```

The output looks like this:

```
thread 0 joined
thread 1 joined
thread 2 joined
thread 3 joined
thread 4 joined
```

indicating that 5 out of the 10 threads aren't exiting (most likely the consumers), and so the program never reaches the end. Is there a condition that isn't being fulfilled, or did I implement the mutexes incorrectly?

Comment: `numProducersWorking` will always be 0 in your consumer loop; so consumers will never finish. You probably don't need that variable anyway; consumers should only care about items, and not how many producers there are, shouldn't they?

Comment: You have a number of race conditions here to be fixed.  For example `consumer()` is reading `items.size()` without any synchronization which is not permissible.

Comment: You have race conditions all over this code. How is a thread in `wait` (called from `consume`) supposed to know that it should terminate? What will get it out of `wait`?

Answer (score 0):

Once the consume thread reaches the condition_variable::wait call inside `consume()`, it will not return without some sort of signal.

I typically have a flag shutdown, which is protected by the same mutex as the queue, and my wait condition is going to be based on the shutdown flag and the size.

When its time for the consumers to stop, I acquire the mutex, and set the shutdown flag.  Then, on exit from the wait, I will either exit immediately on shutdown, or only if the queue is also empty.  The former is an immediate shutdown, while the latter is a shutdown once work is complete.

Also, all access to the items stack must be protected by the mutex.  You've done that in some places, but not others.

Comment: how would I create a shutdown flag?

Comment: `std::atomic<bool> shutdownPlease = false;`